# Check if enum member has been defined?

Tags: c++, enums

I have a long list of enum members defined in a namespace:

```
namespace nsexp{
  enum expname{
    AMS1,
    AMS2,
    BESS1,
    BESS2,
    ...
    };
}
```

It's very useful for me to comment some of them from time to time, something like this:

```
namespace nsexp{
  enum expname{
    AMS1,
    AMS2,
    BESS1,
    //BESS2,
    ...
    };
}
```

so that I can exclude them from my program. However this creates some conflicts in a function where this happens:

```
strcpy(filename[nsexp::BESS2],"bess/data_exp2");
```

I can resolve commenting also this line, but this can be tiring if I'm excluding many of the members. Is there a way to way to check if the member exists within the namespace?

I'm looking for something like:

```
if("BESS2 exists") strcpy(filename[nsexp::BESS2],"bess/data_exp2");
```

Comment: This needs to be done at compile time, an `if()` statement won't help. I'm not sure if it's possible with some template metaprogramming trickery, but even if so, it's questionable if that would be worth it.

Answer (score 2):

build a simple checker object which allows you to interrogate the state of disabled flags at runtime.

```
#include <iostream>

#define RUNTIME_CHECKS 1

namespace nsexp{
    enum expname{
        AMS1,
        AMS2,
        BESS1,
        BESS2,
//        ...
        NOF_EXPNAME
    };


    class checker
    {
#if RUNTIME_CHECKS
        struct impl
        {
            impl() {
                std::fill(std::begin(disabled), std::end(disabled), false);
            }
            bool disabled[NOF_EXPNAME];
        };

        static impl& statics() {
            static impl _;
            return _;
        }

    public:

        static void disable(expname e) {
            statics().disabled[e] = true;
        }

        static bool disabled(expname e)
        {
            return statics().disabled[e];
        }
#else
    public:
        static void disable(expname e) {
            // nop - optimised away
        }

        static bool disabled(expname e)
        {
            // will be optimised away
            return false;
        }
#endif
    };
}

using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    nsexp::checker::disable(nsexp::AMS2);
    nsexp::checker::disable(nsexp::BESS2);

    cout << nsexp::checker::disabled(nsexp::AMS1) << endl;
    cout << nsexp::checker::disabled(nsexp::AMS2) << endl;
    cout << nsexp::checker::disabled(nsexp::BESS1) << endl;
    cout << nsexp::checker::disabled(nsexp::BESS2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
0
1
0
1
```

Comment: `auto` is nice, but isn't it shorter to just write `int main()`?

Comment: i have a skeleton .cpp file that I use to write demo code. It just happens to have main defined this way.

Answer (score 1):

What about defining a reserved value that you can assign to your enum constants:

```
namespace nsexp{
  enum expname{
    AMS1 // = Undefined,
    AMS2 // = Undefined,
    BESS1= Undefined,
    BESS2 // = Undefined,
    ...
    };
}

if (BESS1 != Undefined) strcpy(filename[nsexp::BESS2],"bess/data_exp2");
```

Comment: The way you defined the `enum` will lead to a compilation error because of misplaced/missing commas.

Comment: Lets say `Undefined` is -1. this will make `BESS2` to be equal to Undefined+1, and so  `AMS1` will be equal to `BESS2`. Clearly not what you want. But anyway, it is a nice idea.

Comment: @shr: right, you need to move the identifier to the end of the list as well :(

Comment: I added a slightly different version.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `enum` slightly and check the value before any references.

```
#include <iostream>

enum expname {
  // ENABLED
  AMS1,
  BESS1,
  BESS2,

  // DISABLED
  DISABLED,
  AMS2
};

bool enabled(expname exp) {

  return (exp < expname::DISABLED);
}

int main(const int argc, const char* argv[]) {

  std::cout << enabled(expname::AMS1) ? "enabled" : "disabled" << std::endl;
  std::cout << enabled(expname::AMS2) ? "enabled" : "disabled" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This outputs

```
enabled
disabled
```